# How to skip all tasks that contains "word A" in name?

Tags: android, gradle

Almost all open-source Android apps use Gradle to build nowadays. But in most case they includes many unnecessary (at least for end user at home) tasks and it also takes too long time.

So, I want to skip all those unnecessary tasks in a single shot. For example:

```
onNextTask { // Callback that runs before any task starts
    name = task.name
    if (name.contains("Troll") == true) skip // Skip all tasks that contains "Troll" in name
}
```

...like this(in concept).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer.

```
android {
    // Any settings before

    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {graph ->
        def tasks = graph.getAllTasks()
        tasks.each {task ->
            def name = task.getName()
            //println("TASK_ATTENDED " + task.getName())
            if (name.contains("Troll")) task.setEnabled(false)
            //else println("TASK_CONFIRMED " + task.getName())
        }
    }
}
```

Usually putting it in app/build.gradle would work.

For example, I use this to exclude all release-variant build tasks, unit tests, and linting:

```
android {
    // Any settings before

    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {graph ->
        def tasks = graph.getAllTasks()
        tasks.each {task ->
            def name = task.getName()
            //println("TASK_ATTENDED " + task.getName())
            if (name.contains("elease")) task.setEnabled(false)
            else if (name.contains("Test")) task.setEnabled(false)
            else if (name.contains("lint")) task.setEnabled(false)
            //else println("TASK_CONFIRMED " + task.getName())
        }
    }
}
```